# Show that $x^2 \sin{x} + x \cos{x} + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} > 0$

Tags: inequality

> Show that for any real number $x$:
>    $$x^2 \sin{x} + x \cos{x} + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} > 0.$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $a\sin x+b\cos x\geq -\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

So $$x^2\sin x+x\cos x\geq -\sqrt{x^4+x^2}=-x\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

and $$4x^4+4x^2+1>4x^4+4x^2\Rightarrow (2x^2+1)^2>4x^2(x^2+1)$$

So $$(2x^2+1)>2x\sqrt{x^2+1}\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{1}{2}>x\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

So $$x^2\sin x+x\cos x+x^2+\frac{1}{2}>-x\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\sqrt{x^2+1}=0$$

So $$x^2\sin x+x\cos x+x^2+\frac{1}{2}\gt 0\;\forall x\; \in \mathbb{R}$$

Is my solution is right, If not Then how can we solve it, Help required, Thanks in Advance

Comment: A general remark about your solution: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ rather than $x$. You claim for example that $-\sqrt{x^4+x^2} = -x\sqrt{1+x^2}$, which is false if $x < 0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us check for  $$x^2(1+\sin x)+x\cos x-y=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant  $$\cos^2x+4(1+\sin x)y\ge0$$

Now $1+\sin x\ge0$

Check what if $1+\sin x=0?$

Else $4y\ge\sin x-1\ge-1-(-1)$

Observe that the equality cannot occur as $1+\sin x\ne0$

Answer (score 5):

If we consider $a=(1+\sin x),\, b=\cos(x),\, c=\frac{1}{2}$ we have that
$$ b^2-4ac = \cos^2(x)-2-2\sin(x)=-4\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}\right)^4 \leq 0$$
hence $ax^2+bx+c$ is never negative, since $a\geq 0$ and $\Delta=b^2-4ac\leq 0$.

Comment: What about $x^2 \sin{x} + x \cos{x} + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} = 0 $?

Comment: @McCheng: that is exactly the question I solved. $a=1+\sin x, \; b=\cos x,\; c=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In your answer, you have only proved $x^2 \sin{x} + x \cos{x} + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \ge 0$. You haven't disprove that $x^2 \sin{x} + x \cos{x} + x^2 + \frac{1}{2}$ cannot be equivalence to 0.

Comment: What is missing is the case $\Delta = 0$. In that case $x = 2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But then $\sin(x) = -1$ and $\cos(x) = 0$, so the original equation reduces to $1/2 > 0$ which is clearly true.

Comment: @McCheng:  Left to the interested reader, anyway, it just follows from completing the square.